# Rolling sum product by column

Tags: r, matrix, rcpp

I have two matrices that I would like to multiply together such that each value of the resulting matrix would be a rolling sum-product of the same columns in the first two matrices.

```
x<-matrix(seq(1:30), ncol=3)
x
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1   11   21
 [2,]    2   12   22
 [3,]    3   13   23
 [4,]    4   14   24
 [5,]    5   15   25
 [6,]    6   16   26
 [7,]    7   17   27
 [8,]    8   18   28
 [9,]    9   19   29
[10,]   10   20   30
y<-matrix(rep(seq(1:3), 4), ncol=3)/10
y
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.1  0.2  0.3
[2,]  0.2  0.3  0.1
[3,]  0.3  0.1  0.2
[4,]  0.1  0.2  0.3
```

so the result would look like:

```
1.8 9.9     20.3
2.5 10.7    21.2
3.2 11.5    22.1
3.9 12.3    23
4.6 13.1    23.9
5.3 13.9    24.8
6   14.7    25.7
```

In example output above the value of `10.7` is calculated as:

```
output[2, 2] = 12 * 0.2 + 13 * 0.3 + 14 * 0.1 + 15 * 0.2
```

Does anybody know how to do that?  I have been playing with the `RcppRoll` package but can't get the right answer.  The faster the solution the better since this is part of an optimization that will take many iterations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using colSums:

```
t(
  sapply(1:(nrow(x) - nrow(y) + 1), function(i){
    colSums(x[i:((nrow(y)) + i - 1), ] * y)
    })
  )
```

Based on bigger example data (provided in ZheyuanLi's answer), microbenchmark:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
   zx 179.8928 186.8033 202.5204 192.3973 199.7500 299.5910   100  a 
   ZL 365.9814 368.3878 391.8303 370.0935 373.4502 489.5045   100   b
```

Comment: In the time it took me to think up some representative data you guys already figured it out.  So, to be clear, @zx8754 provided the faster example.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for **[convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)**. In R, the function `convolve` computes convolution of two vectors via FFT (fast Fourier transform). Read `?convolve`. Note, we specifically need `type = "filter"`.

For example, the convolution for `x[,1]` and `y[,1]` is:

```
convolve(x[,1], y[,1], type = "filter")
# [1] 1.8 2.5 3.2 3.9 4.6 5.3 6.0
```

It is straightforward to wrap things up with an `sapply`:

```
sapply(seq_len(ncol(x)), function (i) convolve(x[,i], y[,i], type = "filter"))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  1.8  9.9 20.3
#[2,]  2.5 10.7 21.2
#[3,]  3.2 11.5 22.1
#[4,]  3.9 12.3 23.0
#[5,]  4.6 13.1 23.9
#[6,]  5.3 13.9 24.8
#[7,]  6.0 14.7 25.7
```

---

I think in your context, your matrix `x` is a thin-tall one, i.e., it has much more rows than columns. My `sapply` is along the column. Why not have a practical test and do some profiling?

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(3000 * 100), 3000)  ## `3000 * 100` matrix
y <- matrix(rnorm(100 * 100), 100)  ## `100 * 100` matrix

Rprof("foo.out")
sapply(seq_len(ncol(x)), function (i) convolve(x[,i], y[,i], type = "filter"))
Rprof(NULL)

summaryRprof("foo.out")$by.total

                 total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"sapply"               1.32    100.00      0.00     0.00
"FUN"                  1.30     98.48      0.02     1.52
"lapply"               1.30     98.48      0.00     0.00
"convolve"             1.28     96.97      0.08     6.06
"fft"                  1.12     84.85      1.12    84.85
"rep.int"              0.04      3.03      0.04     3.03
"array"                0.02      1.52      0.02     1.52
"c"                    0.02      1.52      0.02     1.52
"Re"                   0.02      1.52      0.02     1.52
"simplify2array"       0.02      1.52      0.00     0.00
```

`96%+` of the time is spent on `convolve`, thus the overhead of `sapply` is negligible.

Comment: Thank you, this gives me the answer I was looking for.  I am not sure exactly what convolution is but I will read up on it using the link you provided.  My only reservation is that you are using sapply() and I have to do this a lot of time for each optimization.  Won't that slow things down?

Comment: Could also consider this variation: `mapply(convolve, as.data.frame(x), as.data.frame(y), MoreArgs = list(type = "filter"))`

Answer (score 4):

This could be done by `rollapply` in one line like this.  It uses the whole object approach, i.e. no explicit subscripting.

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(x, nrow(y), function(x) colSums(x*y), by.column = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.8  9.9 20.3
[2,]  2.5 10.7 21.2
[3,]  3.2 11.5 22.1
[4,]  3.9 12.3 23.0
[5,]  4.6 13.1 23.9
[6,]  5.3 13.9 24.8
[7,]  6.0 14.7 25.7
```

**Note:** Although not any shorter, using magrittr this could alternately be written as:

```
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)
x %>% rollapply(nrow(y), . %>% `*`(y) %>% colSums, by.column = FALSE)
```